# In vim, what does in normal mode the key Meta-g, Alt-g cause?

Tags: vim

I have unintentionally typed the key ALT-g, equal to Meta-g, to CTRL-] g, and by this my open file was damaged.

In Kubuntu 20.04, Vim version 8.1.

Such problems I have very often, but in former times I have not remembered what I have typed, nor what happened.

This time I know:

Typed:
ALT-g.

Result:
many lines were indented.

I have tried to determine what this key means to vim, what action in vim is invoked.

In vim help I found nothing, and googling in internet yielded nothing.

Please does somebody know about this.

1.
What effectv is caused by the key ALT-g.

2.
Where in vim is this defined.

3.
Does anywhere exist a table for all ALT keys.

4.
Is there a way to disable all keys for which no documentation exist.

Thanks, Regards
Anton Wessel

Comment: According to http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif just move from the top to the bottom of the screen or open file under cursor but that would be `gf`.  Sounds more like a plugin for VIM causing that.  Alt doesn't affect the `g` in any other way.  Normally if you close the file by not writing anything `:q!` then changes shouldn't be saved and the original file should still be intact.

Comment: The VIM forum (https://vi.stackexchange.com/ )is a much better place for this question.